# Inserting an 'image' datatype value through SQL Query/C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-c++

In the application I develop, the database table having a column of 'image' datatype. Now I want to insert the values into that table directly from my program, which is in VC++ 6.0, using a direct ExecuteQuery() of INSERT(due to performance considerations). The image column is been mapped to the structurre of the following declaration

```
typedef struct _DB_BLOB
{
  int size;
  char *data;
}DB_BLOB;
```

The data part will be dynamically filled.

Comment: I want a query to insert a "image" data into my SQL Server table which can be programmatically constructed using VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can construct a hex representation of a string, this insert statement seems to work okay:

```
create table #test
(
    value image 
)

insert #test (value)
values (0x48656C6C6F207468657265)
```

But there may be size limitations (on the size of the query).
It would be really really useful to be able to use managed code and ado.net. to set parameters.